# Parabolic velocity profile in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a parabolic velocity profile such that the parabola is pointing in the **positive x-direction**.

```
from scitools.std import *
def v(y):
    return h**2 - y**2
h = 2
x = linspace(0, 5, 101)
y = linspace(-2, 2, 101)
v = v(y)
plot(x, v)
```

I get the following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/28KpB.png]

This plot is pointing upwards y-axis, but I want the plot to be like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34AQi.png]

but with `y-axis = [-2, 2]` and not `[0, 5]`.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch `x` and `y`:

```
h = 2
y = linspace(-2, 2, 101)
plot(h**2 - y**2, y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Exactly what i was looking for :)